# Mininet WiFi: Stations can ping APs but not vice versa

Tags: python, mininet

I use Virtual Box and I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.5. I have installed mininet Wi-fi and I run a python 3 program. The topology looks like this [topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiDsR.png). All hosts can ping each other and they have internet access, however the stations cannot ping each other and they don't have internet connection. All stations are connected wireless to the APs and all of them can ping the switch which is connected to the APs. I don't see any problem with the code.[links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j9yS.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mn_wifi.cli import CLI
from mn_wifi.net import Mininet_wifi
from mininet.nodelib import NAT
from mininet.node import RemoteController
def topology():
    "Create a network."
    net = Mininet_wifi()

    info("*** Creating nodes\n")
    sta_arg = dict()
    ap_arg = dict()


    s0 = net.addSwitch('s0')
    ap1 = net.addAccessPoint('ap1', ssid='ssid_ap1', mode='a', channel='36',
                             position='10,30,0', range='20')

    ap3 = net.addAccessPoint('ap3', ssid="ssid_ap3", mode="g", channel="10",
                             position='50,30,0', range='20')

    sta1 = net.addStation('sta1', mac='AA:BB:BB:BB:BB:01',
                           defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224',
                           ip='192.168.0.11/240',
                           position='10,40,0')

    sta2 = net.addStation('sta2', mac='AA:BB:BB:BB:BB:02',
                           defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224',
                           ip='192.168.0.12/24',
                           position='15,30,0')

    sta3 = net.addStation('sta3', mac='AA:BB:BB:BB:BB:03',
                           defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224',
                           ip='192.168.0.13/24',
                           position='15,35,0')

    sta4 = net.addStation('sta4', mac='AA:BB:BB:BB:BB:11',
                           defaultRoute='via 10.0.0.22',
                           ip='10.0.0.1/24',
                           position='50,20,0')

    sta5 = net.addStation('sta5', mac='AA:BB:BB:BB:BB:12',
                           defaultRoute='via 10.0.0.22',
                           ip='10.0.0.22/24',
                           position='55,15,0')

    sta6 = net.addStation('sta6', mac='AA:BB:BB:BB:BB:13',
                           defaultRoute='via 10.0.0.22', 
                           ip='10.0.0.3/24',
                           position='45,125,0')

    h1 = net.addHost('h1', ip='192.168.0.1', mac='AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:01',
                     defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224')
    h2 = net.addHost('h2', ip='192.168.0.2', mac='AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:02',
                     defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224')
    h3 = net.addHost('h3', ip='192.168.0.3', mac='AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:03',
                     defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224')
    h4 = net.addHost('h4', ip='192.168.0.4', mac='AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:04',
                     defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224')
    h5 = net.addHost('h5', ip='192.168.0.5', mac='AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:05',
                     defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224')
    h6 = net.addHost('h6', ip='192.168.0.6', mac='AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:06',
                     defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224')

    c1 = net.addController('c1', controller=RemoteController, ip='0.0.0.0',
                            protocol='tcp',port=6633)
   #####################   Link devices to Switch    ######################
    net.addLink(ap1, s0)
    net.addLink(h1, s0)
    net.addLink(h2, s0)
    net.addLink(h3, s0)
    net.addLink(h4, s0)
    net.addLink(h5, s0)
    net.addLink(h6, s0)


    info("*** Configuring wifi nodes\n")
    net.configureWifiNodes()


    ################   Wireless AP Interface   ##########################
    print ("*** Adding Link")
    net.addLink(sta1, ap1, bw=10, loss=5)
    net.addLink(sta2, ap1, bw=10, loss=5)
    net.addLink(sta3, ap1, bw=10, loss=5)

    #####################    NAT1 Interface    ##########################
    net.addLink(sta4, ap3, bw=10, delay=5, loss=5)
    net.addLink(sta5, ap3, bw=10, loss=5)
    net.addLink(sta6, ap3, bw=10, loss=5)

    ######################   Create NAT for Internet   ####################
    nat = net.addHost( 'nat', cls=NAT, ip='192.168.0.224',
                        mac='AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA',
                       subnet='192.168.0.0/24', inNamespace=False)
    net.addLink(nat, s0)


    ###########################     Create RAP        ########################
    nat1=net.addHost('nat1', cls=NAT, ip='192.168.0.22',
                                 mac='AA:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC',
                                 subnet='10.0.0.0/24', inNameSpace=False,
                                 inetIntf='nat1-eth0', localIntf='nat1-eth1',
                                 defaultRoute='via 192.168.0.224')
    net.addLink(nat1,s0)
    net.addLink(ap3, nat1)

    ########################   Add RAP Interface    ########################
    nat1.setIP('10.0.0.22/8', intf='nat1-eth1')


    info("*** Starting network\n")
    net.build()
    ap1.start([c1])

    if '-v' not in sys.argv:
        ap1.cmd('ovs-ofctl add-flow ap1 "priority=0,arp,in_port=1,'
                'actions=output:in_port,normal"')
        ap1.cmd('ovs-ofctl add-flow ap1 "priority=0,icmp,in_port=1,'
                'actions=output:in_port,normal"')
        ap1.cmd('ovs-ofctl add-flow ap1 "priority=0,udp,in_port=1,'
                'actions=output:in_port,normal"')
        ap1.cmd('ovs-ofctl add-flow ap1 "priority=0,tcp,in_port=1,'
                'actions=output:in_port,normal"')

    info("*** Running CLI\n")
    CLI(net)

    info("*** Stopping network\n")
    net.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    topology()
```

Comment: Please share more details - is this even related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase at this point i am not sure if the problem is with the code or mininet. I have attached images of the code that i used to create the topology

Comment: Please post code as **text** - see [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting answers.

Comment: @NicoHaase i have posted the code of the topology.